# Generate random numbers with normal distribution given the mean and the std.dev

Tags: c++, random, generator, distribution, normal-distribution

My question is the following. I have to generate numbers distributed in various way.
I generated the numbers with *uniform distribution* between `1 and 400` with `rand()%400+1`.
Then I have to generate numbers with *normal distribution* with mean `100` and std dev `20`.
Do you know how to do that in *C++*?

I know that random library exist, but I don't know how to use it. Do I have to download it? Should I have *C++11* in my compiler? I have `gcc` in windows and `g++` in ubuntu.

Comment: See [C++11 `<random>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random)

Comment: A couple of points C/C++ is not a language, they are separate programming languages, if you need a *C++* solution that really has nothing to do with *C*. You will usually receive better answers if you provide some code showing what you have attempted and where you are stuck.

Comment: In particular support of juanchopanza's comment see C++11's random library, particularly [`std::normal_distribution<>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/normal_distribution), which is quite-literally *made* for your exact requirements. And that page includes a small sample that demonstrates how to use it.

Comment: But how can I get C++11's random library? I write already in the question, you just remark me to use random, I simply don't know what should I do to have and use it!

Comment: `gcc` has the [C++0x/C++11 Support in GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx0x.html) which details which versions support which C++11 features and how to enable them.

Comment: @mooing-duck thank you, I voted to close before we had the ability to close automatically so could not vote again.